# OpenCV Buffer Overflow

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, buffer-overflow

I've got myself in a pickle on this project I'm working on. My main objective is to stitch two webcam feeds together and do object detection on them - bounding boxes, etc...the standard stuff.

I can't rid myself of buffer overflows though - the somewhat simplified code below (for readability) compiles x64 and soon after I get a buffer overflow error and this in the console:

```
"OpenCV Error: Assertion Failed (contour.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (contour.depth() == CV_32F || CV_32S) in unknown function, file...."
```

If comment out all of the lines that have to do with contours (from `findContours` to `drawBoundingBoxes` in main) it compiles and runs fine until I hit the spacebar to stop the program, and then I get another buffer overflow error. I get the same errors when I compile x32 as well, for the record.

Any help? Relevant code/pseudo-code pasted below:

```
// **defines.h**
//Definitions for anything in all caps, like WIDTH, HEIGHT, ERODEIT, etc...

// **protos.h**
// All function prototypes, nothing else

// **detection.cpp**

/* This is the code that related to background subtraction operations*/

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "defines.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void initBackgroundSubtractor(BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 &bSub)
{
    bSub.set("detectShadows", 1);
}

Mat doBackgroundSubtract(BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 &bSub, Mat panorama)
{
    Mat foreground;

    bSub.operator()(panorama, foreground);
    erode(foreground, foreground, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), ERODEIT, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    dilate(foreground, foreground, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), DILATEIT, BORDER_DEFAULT);

    return foreground;
}

// **contourOps.cpp**

/* Functions that operate on, filter, or relate to OpenCV contours vectors */

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include "defines.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/* Returns the centroid of a contour */

Point getCentroid(vector<Point> contour)
{
    Point centroid;
    Moments m;

    m = moments(contour, false);
    centroid.x = int(m.m10/m.m00);
    centroid.y = int(m.m01/m.m00);

    return centroid;
}

/* Draws a rectangle around a contour */

void drawBoundingBoxes(vector<vector<Point>> contours, Mat &img)
{
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < contours.size(); j++)
    {
        boundRect[j] = boundingRect(contours[j]);
        rectangle(img, boundRect[j], Scalar(153,0,76), 2, 8, 0);
    }
}

/* Removes contours from a vector if they're smaller than the argument "area" */

void contourSizeTrim (vector<vector<Point>> &contours, int area)
{
    vector<vector<Point>>::iterator i = contours.begin();
    while(i != contours.end())
    {
        if(contourArea(*i, false) < area)
            i = contours.erase(i);
        else
            i++;
    }
}

/* Removes contours from a vector if they're X % smaller than largest contour in vector */

void contourRelSizeTrim(vector<vector<Point>> &contours, int percent)
{
    double maxArea = 0.0;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
    {
        if (contourArea(contours[i], false) > maxArea)
                maxArea = contourArea(contours[i], false);
    }

    vector<vector<Point>>::iterator j = contours.begin();
    while(j != contours.end())
    {
        if (contourArea(*j, false) < (double)(percent/100.0)*maxArea)
            j = contours.erase(j);
        else
            j++;
    }
}

// **realtimestitch.cpp**

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "defines.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void initStitcher(VideoCapture &capture1, VideoCapture &capture2, Stitcher &stitch)
{
    capture1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, WIDTH);
    capture1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, HEIGHT);
    capture2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, WIDTH);
    capture2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, HEIGHT);

    detail::OrbFeaturesFinder *featureFinder = new detail::OrbFeaturesFinder(Size(3,1), 1000, 1.5f, 4);
    stitch.setFeaturesFinder (featureFinder);
}

void calcCamTransform(VideoCapture &capture1, VideoCapture &capture2, Stitcher &stitch)
{
    int64 t;
    Mat fr1, fr2, copy1, copy2;
    vector<Mat> imgs;

    capture1 >> fr1;
    capture2 >> fr2;
    fr1.copyTo(copy1);
    fr2.copyTo(copy2);
    imgs.push_back(copy1);
    imgs.push_back(copy2);
    stitch.estimateTransform(imgs);
}

Mat doStitch(VideoCapture &capture1, VideoCapture &capture2, Stitcher &stitch)
{
    Mat fr1, fr2, copy1, copy2, panorama;
    vector<Mat> imgs;

    capture1 >> fr1;
    capture2 >> fr2;
    fr1.copyTo(copy1);
    fr2.copyTo(copy2);
    imgs.push_back(copy1);
    imgs.push_back(copy2);
    Stitcher::Status status = stitch.composePanorama(imgs, panorama);

    if (status != Stitcher::OK)
        cout << "Error Stitching: Code: " << int(status) << endl;

    return panorama;
}

// **main.cpp**

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "defines.h"
#include "protos.h"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    bool doTransform = true, doSizeFilter = true, doRelSizeFilter = true;
    Mat pano, fGround;
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    VideoCapture cap1(0);
    VideoCapture cap2(1);
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bGround;

    initStitcher(cap1, cap2, stitcher);
    initBackgroundSubtractor(bGround);

    while (true)
    {
        if (doTransform)
        {
            calcCamTransform(cap1, cap2, stitcher);
            doTransform = !doTransform;
        }

        pano = doStitch(cap1, cap2, stitcher);
        fGround = doBackgroundSubtract(bGround, pano);


        findContours(fGround, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        if (doSizeFilter)
            contourSizeTrim(contours, AREATHRESH);
        if (doRelSizeFilter)
            contourRelSizeTrim(contours, RELSIZEPERCENT);

        drawBoundingBoxes(contours, pano);

        imshow("Stitched Image", pano);

        if(waitKey(1) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you mark in your code the functino causing error?

Looking at your code I suspect, that problem is that fGroung image returned from background subtractor isn't 8-bit 1-channel image.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours

So first check type of the fGrounf and do some thresholding or type conversion if necessary.

Comment: In my original post I flag at least part of the error - it's somewhere in main.cpp between findContours and drawBoundingBoxes.

I tried adding the line:

foreground.converTo(foreground, CV_8UC1) in the doBackgroundSubtract() function in detection.cpp to no avail.

Comment: Well then, first try to find the exact line causing error. Without knowing which line is causing the problem, we can only guess.

Comment: I've narrowed it down somewhat. The entire program runs fine with only drawBoundingBoxes(contours, pano) commented out. The stitched image "pano" shows up fine, and if I also display the foreground mask "fGround", that shows up and works fine as well. So the stitching and background subtraction works okay. The moment I hit any key to trigger the waitKey() line below it, I get the same error mentioned in my original post. If I uncomment drawBoundingBoxes, I get the same error mentioned in my original post again.

Comment: Well I looked into OpenCV source code without any success. The error is too general to narrow down the problem. I think the issue is, that the extracted countours are wrong. Try to check the contours manually before drawing them. Check point count and such.

Also you could try to draw the contours itself, before filtering and so on, maybe you will find the problem then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem related to OpenCV and VS2012 - on VS2010, there are no problems, and the code runs perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

My opinion about this is that the contour you are trying to do something with an empty vector of contours. Have you verified that? Try a

```
if (contours.empty()) continue; // or here you can display the image to see if it is empty or not
```

I had the same problem because I was trying to give an epty vector to `cv::IsContourConvex(...)` function ([see here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/37517/iscontourconvex-error-215/)).