# OpenCV contourArea() not working

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm pretty new to OpenCV and having a slight problem which is probably something very easy to fix.
Basically im doing some basic image processing, I'm trying to find contours which have an contourArea() of < 3000.

The problem is, I'm getting the following error when trying to draw contours and/or call contourArea() function:

The error is occuring on the `cv:contourArea()` line, the error message is:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (contour.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (contour.depth() == CV_32F || contour.depth() == CV_32S)) in cv::contourArea,
file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 1904
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. The code is below:

```
using namespace cv;

cv::Mat greyMat, binaryMat, newMat;
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("image.png", 1);
// First convert image to gray scale
cv::cvtColor(image, greyMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);

cv::adaptiveThreshold(greyMat, binaryMat, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV, 45, 0);

erode(binaryMat, binaryMat, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(2, 2)));
dilate(binaryMat, binaryMat, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(1, 1)));

// Remove unclosed curves (the circled hashtag)
cv::copyMakeBorder(binaryMat, newMat, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);
cv::floodFill(newMat, cv::Point(0, 0), 255);

newMat = 255 - newMat;

cv::Mat cMat;
newMat.copyTo(cMat);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
cv::findContours(cMat, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

std::cout << "Found: " << contours.size() << " " << contours[0][0] << std::endl;

for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (cv::contourArea(contours[i]) < 3000)
    {
        cv::drawContours(newMat, contours, i, 255, -1);
    }
}

cv::imshow("Debug", newMat);
cv::waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17468345/1601291) demonstrates the same assertion failure on VS 2012. Could you also post an example image where the code fails? This is especially pertinent because I just tried your code and can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but from what I read in the error message, the function expects a floating point value, and you give him vector of vector of `Point`.

According to the [current manual](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point), this type is an integer point, so maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks but no, contourArea returns a double but expects a vector of type Point

Comment: Hmmm. Here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#contourarea, I read `contour – Input vector of 2D points`, but nothing about integer of floating point type. And I just checked the source of `contourArea()` (2.4.5), and it **does** require a `CV_32F` type. Or maybe I missed something ?